# conversion operator to std::complex<double>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-conversion

I have the following piece of code, in which I wrap a generic (POD) type into a (template) class, and define an inner template conversion operator so that I'm able to have implicit conversions between compatible (but different) types. I hope the code is quite self-explanatory. Under no circumstance I can figure out why converting `Foo<double>` to another POD works fine, but a conversion to `std::complex<double>` (typedefed here as `cplx`) fails miserably with

```
error: call of overloaded 'complex(Foo<double>&)' is ambiguous
  cplx z = (cplx)a;
```

Any ideas? Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using cplx = std::complex<double>;

template <typename T>
class Foo // wrapper class for a POD
{
    T val_; // this is the wrapped value
public:
    Foo(T val = {}): val_(val) {};

    template<typename S> // conversion operator
    operator S ()
    {
        std::cout << "Calling conversion operator" << std::endl;
        return val_;
    }
    // stream operator
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &rhs)
    {
        return os << rhs.val_;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<double> a = 10.1;

    // OK, calling the conversion operator double -> int
    int i = 2 + (int)a; 

    // Calling conversion operator double -> cplx
    // this line DOES NOT compile, why?! 
    // cplx z = (cplx)a; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `double`, `float`, and `long double` constructors to `std::complex`.  The compiler doesn't know which to use; it can instantiate `Foo::operator S` with any of them.

If you pick one of them, the compiler can fill in the rest:

```
cplx z = (cplx)(double)a;
```

Comment: thanks, I had the feeling that since I specified `cplx` as being `complex<double>`, the compiler is able to deduce the type. But now I realized that it was template inside template, which is not deduced usually.

Comment: You can also do `a.operator cplx()`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 why can the template be deduced from `operator cplx()` but not from a cast?

Comment: @vsoftco It's not that it can't be deduced, it can (it worked for `int`). The problem is that there are multiple candidates for the cast conversion to `cplx`, neither of which are more viable than the other which thus causes the ambiguity error. Being more specific and calling the conversion operator directly removes any ambiguity.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm a bit confused, so when I call for example `(cplx)a`, don't I just call the templated conversion operator, for which `S=cplx`, which returns the wrapped type that is then converted into `S` in the `return` statement? In other words, why isn't the call `(cplx) a` the same as `a.operator cplx()`?

Comment: @vsoftco `(T)x` is an explicit type conversion . The rules for an explicit type conversion is that they look for constructors and implicit conversion operators to convert the type sucessfully. `std::complex` has several constructors that become candidates along with your class's conversion operator. That's where the ambiguity comes from. If we call the conversion operator explicity it only calls your class's conversion operator. No constructors are considered.